# Can't resolve `AddAuthorization` in my .NET 6 class library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, authorization

So I'm sure I'm missing something super obvious here, but I can't seem to pinpoint it.

I have a .NET 6 class lib:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="6.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have a builder in my lib that is trying to register the `AddAuthorization` service, but it will not resolve for some reason:

```cs
namespace MyLib;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class MyLibBuilder
{
    public IServiceCollection Services { get; }

    public MyLibBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Services = services;
    }

    public MyLibBuilder MapAuthorizationPolicies()
    {
        Services.AddAuthorization();

        return this;
    }
}
```

I've:

- triple checked that I have `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` installed
- Rebuilt the solution
- Unloaded and reloaded the project

And no dice for any. I'm sure it'll click right away once i step away for a day, but it's really bothering me  What the heck am i missing?

> Note: If I change it to a `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` project, it *will* resolve, but then I need a `Main` to run which is moot here since this is just a class lib. `Web` has to be doing something else that I'm missing but i'm not seeing it...

Comment: Do you by any chance have "Authorization" in your namespace?

Comment: nope. tried changing namespace around for good measure just in case. no joy

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/386

Comment: wow, yeah that did it thanks! weird though. i did try using the `...Policy` package as well and that doesn't work even as it -- has to use `Core`. regardlesss, yeah this is weird but solves is. much appreciated!

Comment: Also weird that I have been using, and can even still now, use `AddAuthorization` in a web project just fine without `Core` or using the `Policy` package. still really confused, but nice to have it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/386) this was a breaking change.

The below was the recommended solution, though I did try referencing `Policy` still with no joy.

`Either add a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy or use AddAuthorizationCore instead`